# Int to String Command

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a piece of code that will yell out anything I input.

So the command is 'yell'

I want to be able to type 'yell (whatever i want here)' and it will yell it out. I've been able to do it with numbers but I can't do it with a String. So how can I go about that?

```
int x = Integer.valueOf(cmd[1]);
n.setNextForceTalk(new ForceTalk("Number: " + x));
```

That piece of code allows me to type 'yell (number)' and it will come out with whatever number I type. But how can I do it with text.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `cmd[1]` is a string (one which you want to yell), this should probably work.

```
n.setNextForceTalk(new ForceTalk("String: " + cmd[1]));
```

*Edit* : For printing whole sentence instead of just the first word.

What we want to do is combine the contents of the cmd array into one string to pass to the yell method. Add this code before the `n.setNextForceTalk` line...

```
String sentence = "";
for(int i=1;i<cmd.length;i++){
    sentence = sentence + " " + cmd[i];
}

n.setNextForceTalk(new ForceTalk("String: " + sentence));
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. But now for some reason it only outprints one word like I can type whatever but when i space as if i was typing a sentence it only outs the first word. How can I fix this?

Comment: When you type words with spaces, they will get stored in the cmd array as cmd[1], cmd[2] and so on. Since we are passing only cmd[1] to the method, only the first word will be printed. I'll edit my answer so that the whole sentence will be printed.

Comment: It doesn't work. here is my current code. http://pastebin.com/2n4eEvsT

Comment: To find out what's not working, try adding some System.out.println() statements printing out the values of sentence and cmd[i] during each loop, that way you'll get to know what's going awry. Where is the cmd[] array getting its values?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2n4eEvsT - That's the code, what's happening is the no sentence is printing. Only the first word.

Comment: When you type 'yell (whatever i want here)', where does the whole sentence gets stored? Is it the cmd array or somewhere else? I saw your code, but that is the actual printing part. The problem lies with the part where your (whatever i want here) is getting stored in the array. Could you show me that code?

Comment: There is no other code, that's the only code I have. And the whatever I want here is just I can type whatever like 'yell hey' 'yell whats going on' and it will print my string input.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough code to go on and run the whole thing. Try debugging it yourself with print statements in the loop, and you could probably fix it yourself.